# jqGrid - is it possible to filter the value of jsonmap in colModel

Tags: json, jqgrid

I'm playing around with jqGrid and am wondering if the value of jsonmap in the colModel of jqGrid can have filtered value.

**ColModel**

```
colModel:[
   {name:'fname',index:'action',jsonmap:'cells.cell.colname["fname"].value', width:50, align:"center", resizable:false}
]
```

**JSON**

```
{   
    "rows":[
        {

            "cells":
            {               
                "cell":{
                    "value":"Mark",
                    "colname": "fname"
                }
            }
        }
   ]
}
```

**The value of "cells" property in the JSON input as an array**

```
{   
    "rows":[
        {

            "cells":[
            {               
                "cell":{
                    "value":"Mark",
                    "colname": "fname"
                }
            }]
        }
   ]
}
```

with the following **`colModel`** does not work

```
colModel:[
   {name:'fname',index:'action',jsonmap:'cells.cell.value', width:50, align:"center", resizable:false}
]
```

**To place more than one column and why the suggestion of adding a filter** - I have a problem mapping json with `jsonmap` with the following structure. That is why I asked if we could add a filter.

```
{   
    "rows":[
        {

            "cells":
            {               
                "cell":{
                    "value":"Mark",
                    "colname": "fname"
                },
                "cell":{
                    "value":"Strong",
                    "colname": "lname"
                },
                "cell":{
                    "value":"Hourly",
                    "colname": "emptype"
                }
            }
        }
   ]
}
```

**UPDATED**: The JSON data can be

```
{
    "wrapper": {
        "rows": [
            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "value": "Mark",
                        "colname": "fname"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "Strong",
                        "colname": "lname"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "Hourly",
                        "colname": "emptype"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "cells": [
                    {
                        "value": "Mark2",
                        "colname": "fname"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "Strong2",
                        "colname": "lname"
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "Hourly2",
                        "colname": "emptype"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `jsonmap` as a function

```
jsonmap: function (item) {
    // item.cells.cell.colname is "fname"
    return item.cells.cell.value;
}
```

The option `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }` of jqGrid is additionally required.

One can read the JSON input which you posted (see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11-name-value.htm)), but I still don't understand your suggestion. Why the value of `"cells"` property in the JSON input is object and not an array? Why the property `"cells"` are needed at all? How you imagine to place more as one column in the way? In general you see that in the `jsonmap` function you have access to the whole item from the `"rows"` array, so you can implement any algorithm of reading of fields from the data.

**UPDATED**: I wrote [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11-name-value1.htm) which read the last version of JSON data which you posted. The idea of implementation stay the same - the usage of `jsonmap` as a function.

The column model can be the following

```
colModel: [
    {name: 'fname', jsonmap: function (obj) { return getVaueByName(obj.cells, "fname"); }},
    {name: 'lname', jsonmap: function (obj) { return getVaueByName(obj.cells, "lname"); }},
    {name: 'emptype', jsonmap: function (obj) { return getVaueByName(obj.cells, "emptype"); }}
],
cmTemplate: {width: 70, align: "center", resizable: false},
gridview: true,
height: 'auto',
jsonReader: {
    root: "wrapper.rows",
    page: function () { return 1; },
    total: function () { return 1; },
    repeatitems: false
}
```

where the method `getVaueByName` will be defined as

```
var getVaueByName = function (cells, colName) {
        var i, count = cells.length, item;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
            item = cells[i];
            if (item.colname === colName) {
                return item.value;
            }
        }
        return '';
    };
```

Comment: **Why the value of "cells" property in the JSON input is object and not an array?** - I tried it as an array but data is not displayed using the colModel above. Please see updated post under the heading _"The value of cells property in the JSON input as an array"_

Comment: **How you imagine to place more as one column in the way?** - please see my updated post under the heading _"To place more than one column and why the suggestion of adding a filter"_. Yes, I'm unable to have more than 1 column and have data displayed as per the colModel

Comment: @SK11: If you use `"cells":{}` the `cells` will be *object* with properties. All properties must have **different names**. Your current JSON is buggy. If you use `"cells":[]` the `cells` will be *array* and you can has items with the same properties, but the usage of `{"cell":{ "value":"Mark", "colname": "fname"}}` as items will be syntax error the following is possible: `{"cells": [ {"value": "Mark", "colname": "fname"}, {"value": "Strong", "colname": "lname"}, {"value": "Hourly", "colname": "emptype"}]}`.

Comment: @SK11: On the other side you can place the same information in more compact way as for example `{"columns": ["fname", "lname", "emptype"], "values": ["Mark", "Strong", "Hourly"]}`.

Comment: I changed JSON structure to `{"cells": [ {"value": "Mark", "colname": "fname"}, {"value": "Strong", "colname": "lname"}, {"value": "Hourly", "colname": "emptype"}]}`. **jsonMap:cells.value** not working.

Comment: @SK11: It should not working now because if you change format of input JSON data you have to change the `jsonmap`. `cells.0.value`, `cells.1.value` and `cells.2.value` will get you the values. Nevertheless I still can absolutely not understand why you do all above changes. Two standard representation `{"cells": {"fname": "Mark", "lname": "Strong", "emptype": "Hourly"}}` or {"cells": ["Mark", "Strong", "Hourly"]} are compacter and has the same information.

Comment: You told me that my JSON is buggy and to have it as an array. So, I went ahead and made the change as per your suggestion. Now you're telling me why I made the change. What's the problem?

Comment: I cannot have the JSON structured as per the **Two standard representation** `{"cells": {"fname": "Mark", "lname": "Strong", "emptype": "Hourly"}} or {"cells": ["Mark", "Strong", "Hourly"]}` as there is much more to JSON data than I can share here.

Comment: @SK11: I just tried to follow your suggestion, but you must to make changes in JSON to have no syntax errors. I recommend you always validate JSON in http://jsonlint.com/ before you use it as a proposal. If you need to provide more information in JSON you should write JSON examples having the additional data. You should better *specify the information* and not just write "there is much more to JSON data than I can share here".

Comment: One last thing, Oleg. I'm trying to wrap `rows' with another element such that **{"wrapper":{"rows":[{"cells": [ {"value": "Mark", "colname": "fname"}, {"value": "Strong", "colname": "lname"}, {"value": "Hourly", "colname": "emptype"}]}]}}**. Now, no data is getting displayed.

Comment: @SK11: OK I wrote [one more demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SK11-name-value1.htm) for you which can read the last version of data which you posted.

Comment: So that community members can benefit from our discussion on this thread as well as from your demo, should I be clicking on the tick mark on your very first answer where you say `You can use jsonmap as a function`?

Comment: @SK11: You can include the last version of JSON data in the text of your question and I'll add the code fragments from the last demo and the link in the **"UPDATED"** part of my answer.

Comment: @SK11: I posted the last changes in my answer and in your question. You should modify the text over the **"UPDATED"** part of yoou question like you as want.

Comment: I've added the last version of JSON data in the text of my question. BTW, how are you able to write "@SK11:"? I've been trying to write "@Oleg" in my comments but it just gets deleted.

Comment: @SK11: If you write "@Oleg" in the comment to *my* answer it will be removed because the comments will be addressed to my by default. If I would be write "@SK11" in the comment to *your* question it will be also removed to save the size of comment which is restricted.