# Doctrine returning datetime object instead of date string, jqGrid jsonmap not working

Tags: jquery, json, symfony, doctrine-orm, jqgrid

I'm trying to display date in my jqgrid. But doctrine is returning a datetime object instead of a normal string type value which jqgrid can display.

I can think of two possible solutions:

(1) Change doctrine's return type to somehow return a string so that jqgrid can display it without a problem. (Currently the json is returning an object)

(2) Use jsonmap to manipulate the json (The datetime is coming in as an object but it does display proper data inside)

My code:

(Doctrine related)

```
$qb = $this->em->getRepository('ProductOrderLookupBundle:Product')->createQueryBuilder('u');
$qb->select('u.id, u.productName, u.productDetails,u.shipDate, u');
$qb->getArrayResult();
```

(Jqgrid related)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
                url:"{{ asset('/app_dev.php/_thrace-datagrid/data/user_management') }}",
                datatype: 'json',
                mtype: 'POST',
                colNames:['Product ID','Product Name', 'Product Details', 'Shipment Date', 'Actions'],
                colModel :[
                    {name:'id', index:'u.id', width:200},
                {name:'productName', index:'u.productName', width:200, editable: true},
                {name:'productDetails', index:'u.productDetails', width:200, align:'right', editable: true},
                {name:'shipDate', index: 'u.shipDate', editable: true,jsonmap: function (obj) { return getVaueByName(obj.cells, "date"); }},
                {name:'actions',index:'actions',sortable:false, search:false}
            ],
other jqgrid related code
var getVaueByName = function (cells, colName) {
        var i, count = cells.length, item;
        for (i = 0; i < count; i += 1) {
            item = cells[i];
            if (item.colname === colName) {
                return item.value;
            }
        }
        return '';
    };
```

My json

```
{
  "page":1,
  "total":20000,
  "records":1000000,
  "rows":
    [
      {"id":1,"cell":[1,"Door","Details",{"date":"2012-06-18 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"}]},
      {"id":2,"cell":[2,"Door2","Details2",{"date":"2012-06-18 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"}]},
      {"id":3,"cell":[3,"Door3","Details3",{"date":"2012-06-18 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"}]},
      {"id":4,"cell":[4,"Door4","Details4",{"date":"2012-06-18 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"}]},
      {"id":5,"cell":[5,"Door5","Details5",{"date":"2012-06-18 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"}]},
      {"id":6,"cell":[6,"Door6","Details6",{"date":"2012-06-18 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"}]},
      {"id":7,"cell":[7,"Door7","Details7",{"date":"2012-06-18 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"}]},
      {"id":8,"cell":[8,"Door8","Details8",{"date":"2012-06-18 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"}]},
      {"id":9,"cell":[9,"Door9","Details9",{"date":"2012-06-18 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"}]},
      {"id":10,"cell":[10,"Door10","Details10",{"date":"2012-06-18 00:00:00","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Europe\/Paris"}]}
    ]
}
```

In this all I want is the value under date column. so far I've tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690657/mapping-json-data-in-jqgrid) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144207/jqgrid-is-it-possible-to-filter-the-value-of-jsonmap-in-colmodel) . Both are front end related. I have not been able to find doctrine related solutions. I cannot use `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }` because it doesn't load my data for some reason.

This is what my current grid looks like
[image]

Any kind of solution will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use?

Comment: the jqgrid version is 4.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is something like the following: http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/0fvajwhp/

It uses `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }` first of all, but it uses additionally `jsonmap` property in every column of `colModel`:

```
colModel: [
    {name: 'id', index:'u.id', width: 110},
    {name: 'productName', jsonmap: "cell.1", index:'u.productName', width: 120, editable: true},
    {name: 'productDetails', jsonmap: "cell.2", index:'u.productDetails', width: 120, align:'right', editable: true},
    {name: 'shipDate', jsonmap: "cell.3.date", index: 'u.shipDate', align: "center", formatter: "date", editable: true, width: 120 },
    {name: 'actions', formatter: "actions", width: 70, align: "center", sortable:false, search:false}
]
```

The value `jsonmap: "cell.1"` inform to read first from `cell` property and then get `1` element of the `cell`. To read the date one need to use `jsonmap: "cell.3.date"`. One can use alternatively function form of `jsonmap`:

```
jsonmap: function (obj) { return obj.cell[1]; } // to read productName
```

and

```
jsonmap: function (obj) { return obj.cell[3].date; } // to read date
```

Comment: Oleg to the rescue. Works flawlessly. i wonder why my `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },` didn't work before. Nonetheless, thanks again.

Comment: @DipenShah: It's clear, because `jsonReader: { repeatitems: false }`  interpret the whole item and it expect the data in the format like `{"id":3, "productName":"Door3", "productDetails":"Details3", "shipDate":"2012-06-18 00:00:00"}`. You have another format of data, so you have to inform jqGrid *where* to find the input field in the input item. `jsonmap` do this.

Comment: Oh so in this case I told jqGrid where to find the data rather than the default jqGrid way. That actually makes sense. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should modify a query result a little before passing it to jqGrid, may be like this:

```
$qb = $this->em->getRepository('ProductOrderLookupBundle:Product')->createQueryBuilder('u');
$qb->select('u.id, u.productName, u.productDetails,u.shipDate, u');
$result = $qb->getArrayResult();

$returnValue = [];

foreach ($result as $value) {
    $returnValue[] = [
        'shipDate' => $value['shipDate']->format('Y-m-d' /* which format you wish */) // I assume $value['shipDate'] is returning a DateTIme object
        // other elements go here
    ];
}

// I'm assuming that you're returning a json response;
$response = new JsonResponse();
$response->setData($returnValue);

return $response;
```

Comment: Hi your code work flawlessly. Unfortunately I can only mark one correct answer and I have decided to go with the jqgrid way (I am using a bundle for queries so don't really wanna mess with the bundle). I will give you a vote up tomorrow ( I reached my limit today) Thanks.