# Get The Time From Database in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a field in database (Time) with this value 09:00:00.

I created the Entity and with Time Field

```
 /**
 * @var \DateTime
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="m_01_ch", type="time")
 */
private $m_01_ch;
```

In my controller I retrieve the element and when I do:

```
$val = $myentity->getM01Ch();
```

My value is (in XDebug)

```
$val = {DateTime}[3]
date= "2015-07-08 09:00:00.000000"
timezone_type = 3
timezone "Europe/Rome"
```

If I get `$val->date` I have All the Date, but I want to get only 09:00:00
Can I take my "original" value without use Regex etc?

Comment: Which DB are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can modify your entity where you are returning your value. In your function `getM01Ch()` do something like this

```
/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getM01Ch()
{
    $returnValue = $this->m_01_ch->format('h:i:s') 
    return $returnValue
}
```

Other than that I don't know if any better approach exists. More [info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30381309/4841794)

Comment: h:m:s is the right Format...It works but I have Seven minutes more...In Database I have 9:00:00, but in Controller I Get 09:07:00...

Comment: That's weird. Are you sure you're looking at the right record?

Comment: Yes, all for now is 9:00:00

Comment: That's because m is for month. Do h:i:s and it should work.

Comment: I changed with `$this->m_01_ap->format('H:i:s');` and it works, please change in your snippet

Comment: I have a lot of this fields in the same entity, Can I do a Method to change all of them in "one shot" ?

Comment: You'll probably have to design a custom data type and use that in that case.

Comment: ok, and why I can't use format in Controller? I haven't the same result...Thanks for your time

Comment: You can. However this takes care of it on the entity level so you don't have to use `format` everywhere where you want to use this field.