# Is it a good idea to modify the default getter and setter of a doctrine entities?

Tags: php, entity-framework, symfony, doctrine-orm

I use doctrine to handle my database and I rescently noticed something.

I have a project entity and a projectInt entity (for all the text that needs to be translated). I created a new empty project and two differente projectInt (one for french and the other for english). After creating those, I tried associate both of them to the project like this:

```
    //Crée un nouveau projet
    $nouveauProjet = new Projet();

    //Crée les descriptions
    $descriptionFr = new ProjetInt();
    $descriptionFr->setLangue('fr');
    $descriptionFr->setProjet($nouveauProjet);

    $descriptionEn = new ProjetInt();
    $descriptionEn->setLangue('en');
    $descriptionEn->setProjet($nouveauProjet);
```

Because I'm using a form that use both of the description has collection, when I tried to flush, it gives me an error because it doesn't find the foreign key. I solved this by adding those line:

```
//Associe le projet et les descriptions
$nouveauProjet->addDescription($descriptionFr);
$nouveauProjet->addDescription($descriptionEn);
```

The problème is that I shouldn't have to do that, because when I flush the entity, doctrine usally understand that he need to had the foreign key, but it doesn't seem like he's doing it.

I tought about a solution and here finally comes my question.

I could call the addDescription() fonction inside of the setProjet() fonction, but I don't know if that'S a good idea?

Here are my entites:

```
<?php

namespace PublicBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * Projet
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pt_projet");
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetDepot")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Projet
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    //ID du projet
    protected $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProjetInt", cascade={"persist"}, mappedBy="projet", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    protected $descriptions;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_img", type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     */
    //Nom du fichier de l'image du projet
    protected $image;

    private $imageTemp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_technologie_utilisee", type="text", length=200)
     */
    //Text qui liste tout les technologies utilisées pour le projet
    protected $technologie;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_annee", type="integer", length=4)
     */
    //Année de réalisation du projet
    protected $annee;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Type", inversedBy="projets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pro_type", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    //Clef étrangère du type de projet
    //Le type de projet ne correspond pas à la catégore. Il peu être Unity, flash, image, vidéo, etc. Il permet de savoir quelle page charger pour pouvoir intégrer le projet dans le portfolio.
    protected $type;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_fichier", type="string", length=64, unique=true)
     */
    //Nom du fichier du projet
    private $fichier;

    private $fichierTemp;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_largeur", type="integer")
     */
    //Largeur du projet
    protected $largeur;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pro_hauteur", type="integer")
     */
    //Hauteur du projet
    protected $hauteur;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Categorie", cascade={"persist"})
    */
    //La ou les catégories du projet
    private $categories;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->descriptions=new ArrayCollection();
        $this->categories=new ArrayCollection();
    }


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set image
     *
     * @param string $image
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setImage($image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get image
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

    /**
     * Set technologie
     *
     * @param string $technologie
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setTechnologie($technologie)
    {
        $this->technologie = $technologie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get technologie
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getTechnologie()
    {
        return $this->technologie;
    }

    /**
     * Set annee
     *
     * @param integer $annee
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setAnnee($annee)
    {
        $this->annee = $annee;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get annee
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getAnnee()
    {
        return $this->annee;
    }

    /**
     * Set fichier
     *
     * @param string $fichier
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setFichier($fichier)
    {
        $this->fichier = $fichier;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get fichier
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFichier()
    {
        return $this->fichier;
    }

    /**
     * Set largeur
     *
     * @param integer $largeur
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setLargeur($largeur)
    {
        $this->largeur = $largeur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get largeur
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getLargeur()
    {
        return $this->largeur;
    }

    /**
     * Set hauteur
     *
     * @param integer $hauteur
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setHauteur($hauteur)
    {
        $this->hauteur = $hauteur;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get hauteur
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getHauteur()
    {
        return $this->hauteur;
    }

    /**
     * Add descriptions
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $descriptions
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function addDescription(\PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $descriptions)
    {
        $this->descriptions[] = $descriptions;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove descriptions
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $descriptions
     */
    public function removeDescription(\PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetInt $descriptions)
    {
        $this->descriptions->removeElement($descriptions);
    }

    /**
     * Get descriptions
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getDescriptions()
    {
        return $this->descriptions;
    }

    /**
     * Set type
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\Type $type
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function setType(\PublicBundle\Entity\Type $type)
    {
        $this->type = $type;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get type
     *
     * @return \PublicBundle\Entity\Type 
     */
    public function getType()
    {
        return $this->type;
    }

    /**
     * Add categories
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie $categories
     * @return Projet
     */
    public function addCategory(\PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie $categories)
    {
        $this->categories[] = $categories;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Remove categories
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie $categories
     */
    public function removeCategory(\PublicBundle\Entity\Categorie $categories)
    {
        $this->categories->removeElement($categories);
    }

    /**
     * Get categories
     *
     * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
     */
    public function getCategories()
    {
        return $this->categories;
    }





    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $fichierFile;

    /**
     * Sets fichier file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $fichierFile
     */
    public function setFichierFile(UploadedFile $fichierFile = null)
    {
        $this->fichierFile = $fichierFile;
        //Vérifi s'il y a déja un fichier de projet
        if(isset($this->fichier))
        {
            //Stock l'ancien nom pour l'effacer après la mise à jour
            $this->fichierTemp=$this->fichier;
            $this->fichier=null;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->fichier='initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get fichier file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFichierFile()
    {
        return $this->fichierFile;
    }





    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $imageFile;

    /**
     * Sets image file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $imageFile
     */
    public function setImageFile(UploadedFile $imageFile = null)
    {
        $this->imageFile = $imageFile;
        //Vérifi s'il y a déja un fichier d'image
        if(isset($this->image))
        {
            //Stock l'ancien nom pour l'effacer après la mise à jour
            $this->imageTemp=$this->image;
            $this->image=null;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->image='initial';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get image file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getImageFile()
    {
        return $this->imageFile;
    }



    /**
     * @ORM\PrePersist()
     * @ORM\PreUpdate()
     */
    public function preUpload()
    {
        //S'il y a un fichier pour le projet
        if (null !== $this->getFichierFile())
        {
            //Génère un nom unique
            $nomFichierProjet = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $this->fichier = $nomFichierProjet.'.'.$this->getFichierFile()->guessExtension();
        }

        //S'il y a un fichier pour l'image
        if (null !== $this->getImageFile())
        {
            //Génère un nom unique
            $nomFichierImage = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));
            $this->image = $nomFichierImage.'.'.$this->getImageFile()->guessExtension();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostPersist()
     * @ORM\PostUpdate()
     */
    public function upload()
    {
        if (null !== $this->getFichierFile())
        {
            // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
            // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
            // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
            $this->getFichierFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDirFichier(), $this->fichier);

            //Vérifi s'il y a déja un fichier de projet
            if (isset($this->fichierTemp)) {
                //Efface l'ancien fichier du projet
                unlink($this->getUploadRootDirFichier().'/'.$this->fichierTemp);
                //Efface le chemin temporaire
                $this->fichierTemp = null;
            }
            $this->fichierFile = null;
        }

        if (null !== $this->getImageFile())
        {
            // if there is an error when moving the file, an exception will
            // be automatically thrown by move(). This will properly prevent
            // the entity from being persisted to the database on error
            $this->getImageFile()->move($this->getUploadRootDirImage(), $this->image);

            //Vérifi s'il y a déja un fichier d'image
            if (isset($this->imageTemp)) {
                //Efface l'ancienne image du projet
                unlink($this->getUploadRootDirImage().'/'.$this->imageTemp);
                //Efface le chemin temporaire
                $this->imageTemp = null;
            }
            $this->imageFile = null;
        }  
    }



    /**
     * @ORM\PostRemove()
     */
    public function removeUpload()
    {
        $fichierFile = $this->getAbsolutePathFichier();
        if ($fichierFile) {
            unlink($fichierFile);
        }

        $imageFile = $this->getAbsolutePathImage();
        if ($imageFile) {
            unlink($imageFile);
        }
    }



    public function getAbsolutePathFichier()
    {
        return null === $this->fichier
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDirFichier().'/'.$this->fichier;
    }

    public function getWebPathFichier()
    {
        return null === $this->fichier
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDirFichier().'/'.$this->fichier;
    }



    public function getAbsolutePathImage()
    {
        return null === $this->image
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadRootDirImage().'/'.$this->image;
    }

    public function getWebPathImage()
    {
        return null === $this->fichier
            ? null
            : $this->getUploadDirImage().'/'.$this->image;
    }



    //Le chemin absolu du répertoire où le fichier du projet se trouve 
    protected function getUploadRootDirFichier()
    {
        return __DIR__.'/../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDirFichier();
    }

    //Le chemin absolu du répertoire où l'image du projet se trouve 
    protected function getUploadRootDirImage()
    {
        return __DIR__.'/../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDirImage();
    }



    protected function getUploadDirFichier()
    {
        return 'bundles/public/projets/'.$this->getType()->getNom();
    }

    protected function getUploadDirImage()
    {
        return 'bundles/public/projets/vignettes';
    }
}
```

The description:

```
<?php

namespace PublicBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Projet Inter
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="pt_projet_int");
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PublicBundle\Entity\ProjetIntDepot")
 */
class ProjetInt
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    //ID de la description
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Projet", inversedBy="descriptions")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pro_id_CE", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     */
    //Clef étrangère du projet associé
    protected $projet;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pri_lang", type="string", length=2)
    */
    //Langue de la carégorie
    protected $langue;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pri_nom", type="string", length=30)
     */
    //Nom du produit
    protected $nom;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pri_description_cours", type="text",length=100)
     */
    //Description cours du projet
    protected $descriptionCours;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pri_description_complete", type="text",length=250)
     */
    //Description complete du projet
    protected $descriptionComplete;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pri_roles", type="string",length=60)
     */
    //Roles joués dans la création du projet
    protected $roles;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="pri_aptitudes_developpees", type="string",length=200)
     */
    //Aptitudes développées lors du projet
    protected $aptitudesDeveloppees;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set langue
     *
     * @param string $langue
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setLangue($langue)
    {
        $this->langue = $langue;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get langue
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLangue()
    {
        return $this->langue;
    }

    /**
     * Set nom
     *
     * @param string $nom
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setNom($nom)
    {
        $this->nom = $nom;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nom
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNom()
    {
        return $this->nom;
    }

    /**
     * Set descriptionCours
     *
     * @param string $descriptionCours
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setDescriptionCours($descriptionCours)
    {
        $this->descriptionCours = $descriptionCours;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descriptionCours
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescriptionCours()
    {
        return $this->descriptionCours;
    }

    /**
     * Set descriptionComplete
     *
     * @param string $descriptionComplete
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setDescriptionComplete($descriptionComplete)
    {
        $this->descriptionComplete = $descriptionComplete;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get descriptionComplete
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescriptionComplete()
    {
        return $this->descriptionComplete;
    }

    /**
     * Set roles
     *
     * @param string $roles
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setRoles($roles)
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get roles
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        return $this->roles;
    }

    /**
     * Set aptitudesDeveloppees
     *
     * @param string $aptitudesDeveloppees
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setAptitudesDeveloppees($aptitudesDeveloppees)
    {
        $this->aptitudesDeveloppees = $aptitudesDeveloppees;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get aptitudesDeveloppees
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getAptitudesDeveloppees()
    {
        return $this->aptitudesDeveloppees;
    }

    /**
     * Set projet
     *
     * @param \PublicBundle\Entity\Projet $projet
     * @return ProjetInt
     */
    public function setProjet(\PublicBundle\Entity\Projet $projet)
    {
        $this->projet = $projet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get projet
     *
     * @return \PublicBundle\Entity\Projet 
     */
    public function getProjet()
    {
        return $this->projet;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just use translatable doctrine extension.

Comment: The question is does it work for you? If yes, then yeah definitely go ahead and modify it. I personally [do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31463505/return-date-from-doctrine-query/31463599#31463599) it in my project and it seems to be working fine.

Comment: First, I don't use translatable doctrine extension, because frenquly, it gives me headaches and my application is almost finish, so if I started from the start, I would have use it, but not in this case. Second You're shure? I'm afraid of making some loop by doing that. Could that be the case?

Comment: yes, is a good idea and sometime is a bad practice. BUT most symfony2 components (like the Form)  is based on the getter/setter you define on the undeling data you specify to manage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Matteo wrote:

yes, is a good idea and sometime is a bad practice. BUT most symfony2 components (like the Form) is based on the getter/setter you define on the undeling data you specify to manage.